# docker network use host mode not working(no port expose)

Tags: docker, networking, port, host

This is my information:

```
➜  ~ docker -v
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea
➜  ~ uname -ar
Darwin Felixs-iMac.local 19.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 19.2.0: Sat Nov  9 03:47:04 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.61.1~20/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

when I create a docker with host network mode like this (which is copied from https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/)

`docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx`

It worked well and I can see the docker is running. 
BUT THE PROBLEM IS the port isn't exposed.
when i check with `lsof -i:80`, there's nothing.

```
➜  ~ docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx
282fe15a16b70d7bd38b770fd2b67f0023b8fce1f9852a91af4047ef8f6a3f0d
➜  ~ lsof -i:80
➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                               NAMES
282fe15a16b7        nginx                   "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute
```

And i inspected the container, everything seems good:

```
➜  ~ docker inspect my_nginx
[
    {
        "Id": "282fe15a16b70d7bd38b770fd2b67f0023b8fce1f9852a91af4047ef8f6a3f0d",
        "Created": "2020-02-26T15:35:58.243963941Z",
        "Path": "nginx",
        "Args": [
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 2238,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2020-02-26T15:35:58.39452216Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:2073e0bcb60ee98548d313ead5eacbfe16d9054f8800a32bedd859922a99a6e1",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/282fe15a16b70d7bd38b770fd2b67f0023b8fce1f9852a91af4047ef8f6a3f0d/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/282fe15a16b70d7bd38b770fd2b67f0023b8fce1f9852a91af4047ef8f6a3f0d/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/282fe15a16b70d7bd38b770fd2b67f0023b8fce1f9852a91af4047ef8f6a3f0d/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/282fe15a16b70d7bd38b770fd2b67f0023b8fce1f9852a91af4047ef8f6a3f0d/282fe15a16b70d7bd38b770fd2b67f0023b8fce1f9852a91af4047ef8f6a3f0d-json.log",
        "Name": "/my_nginx",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": true,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Capabilities": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/062cb6ccb41fb22ba624fb8f93e99e79bcf02cd240fbb4998e47aab1380e015f-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/587f9f458f8f0de65434971354636364ff685701fa1f8ba0ba7da4459e22540c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1a94586d0949b8305ac14f0934a46149b31db3eb6e7125d7b2965deef318695d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/ac900d4637ed15f3337e999928ec2a9de2ef4a998f4ce53700a1dffc955d5f0e/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/062cb6ccb41fb22ba624fb8f93e99e79bcf02cd240fbb4998e47aab1380e015f/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/062cb6ccb41fb22ba624fb8f93e99e79bcf02cd240fbb4998e47aab1380e015f/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/062cb6ccb41fb22ba624fb8f93e99e79bcf02cd240fbb4998e47aab1380e015f/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "docker-desktop",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "NGINX_VERSION=1.17.8",
                "NJS_VERSION=0.3.8",
                "PKG_RELEASE=1~buster"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "Image": "nginx",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "maintainer": "NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>"
            },
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "be4dc476e331bb8ac857ec069d0aa8383d7700ba5b917c0fed44c59d0b042c99",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "56456bd40ca98647fed01509408599accfadc7cb0f0077ea884b18fc009801b5",
                    "EndpointID": "e3e870245e2995fbfbae8706fa2daa19f3bf3d59d11d2f8ce2300f2b84b211e0",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: [Host networking doesn’t work on MacOS hosts.](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) You shouldn’t need it for most things; what are you trying to accomplish, that Docker’s normal `docker run -p` port mapping wouldn’t do?

Comment: (Note that if you do use `--net host`, it basically entirely disables Docker’s network stack, so you won’t see published ports in the `docker ps` output.  “Expose” as a Docker verb doesn’t have much of a practical effect at all.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MacOS, then host network mode will not work on it, the reason for that is that docker-desktop uses an underlying Linux Virtual Machine to run the docker containers, so this host mode is only valid for that VM's network and not for the host(MacOS machine).

Still if you want to access a service running on your host machine(MacOS), from your docker container then you need to use the following hostname in order to connect to that service:

```
host.docker.internal
```

You'll be using the above hostname in place of `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`.

For further discussion regarding this you check this [github issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3800)